# Write results of SQL sub query back to database

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been playing with this SQL code:

```
SELECT
    id,
    @prev := @curr as prev,
    @curr := measure as curr,
    @rank := IF(@prev > @curr, @rank+@ties, @rank) AS rank,
    @ties := IF(@prev = @curr, @ties+1, 1) AS ties,
    (1-@rank/@total) as percentrank
FROM
    mytable,
    (SELECT
        @curr := null,
        @prev := null,
        @rank := 0,
        @ties := 1,
        @total := count(*) from mytable where measure is not null
    ) b
WHERE
    measure is not null
ORDER BY
    measure DESC
```

I'd like to write the calculated 'percentrank' back to each corresponding row of mytable in a column named "percentile," but I can't recall how to work in my update statement.

I appreciate the help.

Credit to http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/sql-ranking-without-self-join for the SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update from a subquery, give the subquery an alias so that it's a derived table.  Then use this syntax:

```
update YourTable
set SomeField = DerivedTable.something
, etc
from YourTable join
(subquery goes here) DerivedTable on YourTable.Whatever  = DerivedTable.Whatever
etc
```